# How to log in HibernateCriteriaBuilder

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, criteria

I try log some details in a namedQuery for a grails domain class but logging errors.

```
static namedQueries = {
  firstThree {
    if (booleanValue) {
       log.trace "booleanValue = true"
       eq ('bar', foo)
    }
    maxResults(3)
  }
}
```

Error

```
No such property: log for class: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder
```

How do I log in a criteria?

Comment: I've removed my answer since it doesn't work. I'm not sure how to do this within a named query. It seems like there might be a different way to approach the problem, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the log property isn't static so it's not visible from the static closure. You could create your own static logger and use that, e.g.

```
static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger('some.logging.category.name')
```

and then use that:

```
static namedQueries = {
  firstThree {
    if (booleanValue) {
       LOG.trace "booleanValue = true"
       eq ('bar', foo)
    }
    maxResults(3)
  }
}
```